# API to find the number of instances run by hour - AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am looking for API that can return number of instances that run during the course of the day for each of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

If it was my task, I would create a php script that runs in cron job every hour and record EC2 instances information (Running number of instances a part of that) in the database.

Then just query the database to with the right parameters.